# Python-msfrpc, whats is wrong

Tags: python

```
def pwn_run():
    client = msfrpc.Msfrpc({})
    client.login('msf','abc123')
    try:
            res = client.call('console.create')
            console_id = res['id']
    except:
        print "Console create failed\r\n"
        sys.exit()
    con_job_DUMP=client.call('console.read', [console_id])

    print console_id;
```

It's always return:

> Console create failed
>
> and res =`{'error_backtrace':
>   ("lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/rpc_console.rb:15:in`rpc_create'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:152:in `block in process'",
>   "lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in`timeout'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:152:in `process'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:90:in`on_request_uri'",
>   "lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:72:in `block in start'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:in`call'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:in `on_request'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:365:in`dispatch_request'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:299:in `on_client_data'",
>   "lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:158:in`block in start'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:in `call'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:in`on_client_data'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:192:in `block in monitor_clients'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:in`each'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:in `monitor_clients'",
>   "lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:73:in`block in start'",
>   "lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:in `call'",
>   "lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:in`block in spawn'",
>   "lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:in `call'",
>   "lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:in`block in spawn'"),
>   'error_message': 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)', 'error_class':
>   'ArgumentError', 'error_string': 'wrong number of arguments (2 for
>   1)', 'error': True}`

What's wrong with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having some similar problem! I tried making several virtual consoles but apparently you can't for some reason!

You probably have several sessions open. Try to just have one open. And also remember to:

> `msfconsole`
>
> `msfrpc load Pass=<password>`

in another window